# How does CryptoChefs fullbit encryption (Vollbit-Verschlüsselung) work

Tags: encryption, cryptography

After studying [CryptoChefs homepage](http://www.kryptochef.de/) about "fullbit encryption" (Vollbit Verschlüsselung), I just wondered if there has already been an analysis on how this algorithm works.

I believe he just xors some file with another file, maybe multiple times, but maybe someone still knows what he really does.

Comment: Sounds like this guy doesn't know what he's talking about. He claims that 256 bit is the largest possible key size based on some confused logic. Clearly this is wrong (Blowfish, for example, supports key sizes up to 448 bits). Stay away, I say! Use an algorithm that has had proper cryptanalysis.

Comment: At least based on the "English" description, I don't think it's possible to even guess.

Comment: The homepage does not give any information, and it is clear that there are no demo version because if there were, anyone would see how bad his algorithms are. Just asking for curiosity.

Comment: This is clearly snakeoil. How it works is pretty irrelevant, I think, and can almost certainly be summed up as "not very well".

Comment: he is a well known troll in the german webcommunity

Answer (score 1):

I think its no that easy as chefin says, because he claims it works with a passphrase to generate the keyfile.

So, if the software exists, it will be flawed, because a keyfile for XOR generated by a passphrase will contain redundancies. just think of the easiest way to generate a keyfile from a password:

passwordpasswordpassword

Now you can just split the ciphertext in three blocks (each with the length of the password) and XOR two of them together to get the password.

Of course, there are more sophisticated algorithms for generating keyfiles from a password, but none of them will have the OTP-Feature of "nobody can decrypt it without the pad", because the pad depends on the passphrase and cannot have more entropy than the passphrase itself.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but it works "perfect". But thats normal, as he only create a onetimepad encryption. If you use random numbers (and thats why he speak about 256bit key) and generate a file as big as the file you want to encrypt, simple xor multiple times is enough.

But this is old and everyone know it is not usefull. How do you store a 2Mbyte File you need to decrypt your 2Mbyte Dokument. Use a Stick? Why not put the file on the stick itself? It is just a little harder for decrypting, as you need 2 components you have to find first.